# Database Mirroring in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, database-administration

I'm not a DBA but I hear that database mirroring is deprecated or about to be, I'm using SQL 2014, in my company they are using database mirroring, which is exactly the new version? it is something we can implement on SQL Server 2014 or we need to have a newer version installed? I want to convince people that database mirroring should be replaced.

Comment: This question should be on DBA community.

Comment: Sorry how to do that? Ok I found the category, I replaced it by that one, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

AlwaysOn [Availability Groups](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/database-engine/availability-groups/windows/overview-of-always-on-availability-groups-sql-server?view=sql-server-2017) (AGs) are the replacement for Database Mirroring.  You can stay on Mirroring on SQL 2014 if it works for you, but when you upgrade you should plan on migrating to AGs.  If you're on Standard Edition, you can use [Basic Availability Groups](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/database-engine/availability-groups/windows/basic-availability-groups-always-on-availability-groups?view=sql-server-2017) which have the same capabilities as Database Mirroring on Standard Edition.

Comment: Thank you David, we have Enterprise edition, can we implement it now on SQL Server 2014?

Comment: Yes, but you'll need to create a Windows Failover Cluster (no shared disks needed), and replace the Witness with a cluster quorum model.  If you want to take advantage of the additional features of AGs like readable secondaries, backup from secondary, etc it might be worth doing.  But Mirroring is still supported, even in SQL 2017, so there's no requirement to change what you're doing.

Comment: thank you so much David!, my concern is that database mirroring could be blocking some regular process, like rebuild indexes on all databases or so...

Comment: Architecturally AGs and Mirroring are basically the same.  All the log records from the primary are sent to the secondary(ies) and replayed there.  Rebuilding indexes generate lots of log records, but shouldn't be blocked by either one.